# losetup: cannot find an unused loop device

Tags: mount, disk

I am following along with a tutorial trying to learn how to work with Linux. I created a disk file with the command `fallocate -l 1G disk1.img` and now I would like to add a loop device. However when I run `losetup -f --show disk1.img` as described in the tutorial it errors with:

```
losetup: cannot find an unused loop device
```

Reading the man page for losetup it states that `-f --show` should:

```
Find  the first unused loop device. If a file argument is present, use this device. Otherwise, print its name
```

Does this mean I cannot add anymore loop devices?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo`?